# Sum based on text values - Excel

Tags: excel

I'm working in Excel and have a report with columns similar to this -

[image: Original Table Data.]

I would like the output to group the Colors (in Column B) and show the total sum for each color. Similar to this -

[image: Desired Output.]

Ideally the output could be shown in a new sheet, but not necessary if that makes it more complicated.

Any suggestions would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add column headings to your first table, like "Category", "Colour", "Value". Then click Insert > Pivot Table. Drag the Colour field into the Rows area and the Value field into the Values area.

[image]